# How do you automatically fix pan in Equirectangular 360 video?

Tags: premiere, davinci-resolve, stabilisation, 360video, vr

I have used a GoPro Max to record a long video.

- 8 hours.
- indoor.
- well lit.
- static on a monopod.
- spherical (360).

Unfortunately, the "World Lock" pan stabilisation messed up (not sure why) so now the world slowly spins left, even though the camera did not physically move whatsoever. I have also tried turning off World Lock but the problem persists. Being well lit, indoor footage, there are plenty of clearly defined reference points that could be used for tracking.

I have seen that it is possible to do [manual motion tracking](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aRI1cjM1UHE) using keyframes in Premiere Pro, and that the automatic tracking only works with masks. With so much footage, however, manual methods are not really feasible. Is there a way to automatically fix the pan using tracking points?

Tagged with Premiere Pro and Resolve as I have both. Don't mind which one I use. If you have a better suggestion than either of these, I'm all ears.

Apologies in advance if this is a bit of a newbie question!